# How do you print out the index of a list element in an ordered list?

Tags: javascript, dynamic

I have this code that on a button click, it spawns a group of elements inside a list. each of this groups is indexed in the ordered list in ascending order 1,2,3 etc.. i need these numbers to be stored for use in my database.
currently I haven't been able to find a way to identify the index number of each group in the list and thus add them as attributes.
This is my JS for spawning a group:

```
function spawnSilly() //spawn chapters function
        {
            var div = document.createElement("LI");
            var input = document.createElement("INPUT");
            var button = document.createElement("BUTTON");
            var del_button = document.createElement("BUTTON")
            input.setAttribute("type", "text");
            input.setAttribute("placeholder", "Title");
            input.setAttribute("id", "var timestamp = new Date().getUTCMilliseconds();")
            button.setAttribute("type", "button");
            button.setAttribute("onClick", "redirect()");
            button.setAttribute("id", "var timestamp = new Date().getUTCMilliseconds();")
            button.innerHTML = "Edit";
            div.setAttribute("id", "var timestamp = new Date().getUTCMilliseconds();")
            del_button.setAttribute("id", "var timestamp = new Date().getUTCMilliseconds();")
            del_button.innerHTML = "Delete";
            del_button.setAttribute("onClick", "removeElement(this.id)")
            div.appendChild(input)
            div.appendChild(button)
            div.appendChild(del_button);

            var list = document.getElementById("spawnList");
            list.insertBefore(div, list.childNodes[0]);
            set_index();
        }
```

I've been using this JS code to add an index, but I cannot tell if it's working as I cant print out the index of a spawned list element.

```
function set_index()
        {
            var ol = document.getElementById('spawnList');

            // select the list items
            var lists = ol.getElementsByTagName('li');

            var l = lists.length; // total items
            //custom list id's via loop
            for (var i=1;i<=l;i++)
            {
            list[i].index = i;
            }

        }
```

This is my HTML:

```
<ol id="spawnList">


    </ol>
    <button id="spawnbtn" onClick="spawnSilly(); ">Add</button>
```

This is really bugging me, any help would be fantastic! Thanks :)

Comment: You're trying to get the number from each `<li>` under the `<ol>` (ordered list)? There's no need for that. Just get all the `<li>` elements, and loop over them (like you already did), and add `1` to the current index. e.g. `var listNumber = i + 1;`. JS always gets elements in a top down fashion, which is exactly how your list is ordered.

Comment: Okay cool, and how would you print each Li list number out?

Comment: `console.log(i + 1);` and you can view this output by opening your developer console on your browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change way to add li tag in ol tag and it show index.

```
var list = document.getElementById("spawnList");         

  list.appendChild(div);
```

```js
var index = 1;
function spawnSilly() //spawn chapters function
        {
            var div = document.createElement("LI");
            var input = document.createElement("INPUT");
            var button = document.createElement("BUTTON");
            var del_button = document.createElement("BUTTON")
            input.setAttribute("type", "text");
            input.setAttribute("placeholder", "Title");
            input.setAttribute("id", "var timestamp = new Date().getUTCMilliseconds();")
            button.setAttribute("type", "button");
            button.setAttribute("onClick", "redirect()");
            button.setAttribute("id", "var timestamp = new Date().getUTCMilliseconds();")
            button.innerHTML = "Edit";
            div.setAttribute("id", "var timestamp = new Date().getUTCMilliseconds();")
            del_button.setAttribute("id", "var timestamp = new Date().getUTCMilliseconds();")
            del_button.innerHTML = "Delete";
            del_button.setAttribute("onClick", "removeElement(this.id)")
            div.appendChild(input)
            div.appendChild(button)
            div.appendChild(del_button);

            var list = document.getElementById("spawnList");
            
            //var li = document.createElement("li");
            
  
  list.appendChild(div);
            console.log(index++);
            //list.insertBefore(div, list.childNodes[0]);
            //set_index();
        }

function set_index()
        {
            var ol = document.getElementById('spawnList');

            // select the list items
            var lists = ol.getElementsByTagName('li');
            if(lists != undefined){
              var l = lists.length; // total items
            //custom list id's via loop
            for (var i=1;i<=l;i++)
            {
            list[i].index = i;
            }
            }

          

        }
```

```html
<ol id="spawnList">


    </ol>
    <button id="spawnbtn" onClick="spawnSilly(); ">Add</button>
```

Comment: How would i print their indexes though?

Comment: where do you want to print index?

Comment: just anywhere, so that i could see them, could even use an alert, it would be great if it printed next to the li though with a string so: "my index is" + index

Comment: I updated answer, only need declare a global index outside and increase it after you append to ol tag.